# Merge 2 variables htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 fields in my database IP and port,
when retrieve them from the database I join them in a link.

I am using mod rewrite I also remove the .php so if server_info.php turns to server_info.

i echo out this link on my page

```
echo'<a href="'.URI.'/server_info/'.$IP.':'.$Port.'">';
```

and my mod rewrite for the link is

```
RewriteRule ^server_info/([^/][0-9]*)$ server_info.php?IP&Port=$1 [L]
```

but when i click its not giving any info

if i type it like this

```
http://localhost/server_info.php/70.85.442.13:70215
```

it works

if i type it like this

http://localhost/server_info/70.85.442.13:70215
it dont work

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work perfectly

```
RewriteRule server_info/(.*):(.*) server_info.php?IP=$1&Port=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` (which doesn't work; has `/` instead of `?`) and what you type in (which works; has `?`) are different.

```
echo'<a href="'.URI.'/server_info?'.$IP.':'.$Port.'">';
```

UPDATE: If for some reason, you don't want to change the URL in your `echo` then you need to fix the regex in your rewriterule.  Right now it is looking for any non-slash character (`[^/]`) followed by zero or more digits (`[0-9]*`).  This doesn't match your IP with `.`s, `:`, and port.  You might want something like

```
RewriteRule ^server_info/([\.0-9]*):([0-9]*)$ server_info.php?$1&Port=$2 [L]
```

`[\.0-9]*` will match dots and digits, your IP address, captured in `$1`.  `[0-9]*` will capture digits, your prot, in `$2`.

UPDATE:  See:  https://regex101.com/r/ylURsz/1

Comment: not sure whats going on with it it give internal error if i type http://localhost/server_info.php/70.85.442.13:70215 no problem